# MariaDB won't start for my MariaDB Galera Cluster node

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I have configured a MariaDB Galera cluster with three nodes. The master node and one of the slave-master node is up and running, but the third node just won't run. The system specs and cluster config are the same on all three nodes (except changing the wsrep_node_address and the wsrep_node_name on each node).

Here is the config for the nodes (wsrep_node_address and the wsrep_node_name are unique on each node):

```
[galera]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.1.111,192.168.1.112,192.168.1.113"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.9.113'
wsrep_node_name='george-db4'
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup
wsrep_sst_auth=username:password
```

It seems like MariaDb does not like the config

```
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.1.111,192.168.1.112,192.168.1.113"
```

Because when i comment it out, MariaDB restarts just fine. But when i uncomment it, it just displays this message:

```
Starting MySQL................................... ERROR! 
ERROR! Failed to restart server.
```

When i change the wsrep_cluster_address to just wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://, MariaDb runs with no problem. So i am not sure while it is having problems with assigning the IP address (even if it works fine on the other two nodes). I have tried empting the galera.cache file, i have tried re-installing the cluster, i have tried rebooting the machine etc and nothing works so far. I even truncated the log file /var/lib/mysql/db1.err with the command truncate logfile --size 0 (now i cannot figure out how to get my log file back with space as i realized i would need the log file).

Comment: are you able to find a solution? I've googled whole internet.. no idea what's going on!

Comment: Not sure if you still need help on this but I figured this out. Let me know if you are still interested

Comment: Of course, we are interested. This always happens if all cluster nodes where completly shutdown. There seem to be no way to get the wsrep_last_committed without mariadb running and also no way to get mariadb running without one random host bootstrapped. Wich sucks. With the gcomm:// line mariadb requires at least one peer to be reachable wich isn't possible if no instance of mariadb starts anywhere because no other instance starts anywhere. Therefore all manuals fail at the point "getting the most advanced node"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue. It's like Galera won't see my garlera.conf file, even though it's included in the my.cnf.

I've found that adding the parameters to the serviced command is the way to get around this:

```
sudo service mysql start --wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.1.111,192.168.1.112,192.168.1.113" --wsrep_cluster_name="galera_cluster"
```